# Lost the website after installing Wordpress in CPanel

Tags: php, css, wordpress, backup, cpanel

After installing WordPress on a live website it's just showing the welcome page of Wordpress. I have full backup of the site but I don't know how to get the site back.
Please help out

Comment: Just restore the files back into the public html folder. You might want to delete wordpress first. P.S. Not sure why you installed wordpress when you already had an existing site? It's not really intended to co-exist with other stuff.

Comment: Wanted to change the template.... Thank you so much for helping. Appreciate it